# Openvpn installation failure with " 'IP' has no attribute 'SubnetSet'"

Tags: networking, python, openvpn

I am trying to install an openvpn Software Packages at a new EC2 instance. After running: 
sudo dpkg -i openvpn-as-2.1.4b-Ubuntu16.amd_64.deb

The deb package is downloaded from https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw/113.html?osfamily=Ubuntu

The message shows the installation fails, and the message in the log is:

```
Once you provide a few initial configuration settings,
OpenVPN Access Server can be configured by accessing
its Admin Web UI using your Web browser.

Will this be the primary Access Server node?
(enter 'no' to configure as a backup or standby node)
> Press ENTER for default [yes]: 

Please specify the network interface and IP address to be
used by the Admin Web UI:
(1) all interfaces: 0.0.0.0
(2) eth0: 172.31.23.191
Please enter the option number from the list above (1-2).
> Press Enter for default [2]: 

Please specify the port number for the Admin Web UI.
> Press ENTER for default [943]: 

Please specify the TCP port number for the OpenVPN Daemon
> Press ENTER for default [443]: 

Should client traffic be routed by default through the VPN?
> Press ENTER for default [yes]: 

Should client DNS traffic be routed by default through the VPN?
> Press ENTER for default [yes]: 

Use local authentication via internal DB?
> Press ENTER for default [no]: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/_ovpn-init", line 478, in <module>
    priv_nets = NetInfoLinux.get_priv_subnets()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyovpn/net/net.py", line 403, in get_priv_subnets
AttributeError: type object 'IP' has no attribute 'SubnetSet'
```

The OS: `Linux ip-172-31-23-191 3.13.0-106-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 6 15:44:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and Python is　２．７．６

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this package is made for your version of Ubuntu? Package name sounds like it's for Xenial, while your uname with `3.13.x` `#153-Ubuntu`: sounds like Trusty.

Assuming you just want OpenVPN, you may go with `apt-get install openvpn` instead of your `dpkg`. As a general rule: avoid using `dpkg` directly.

Comment: I am trying to install openvpn, access server, and web admin in one time. The package should be right from the donwload url. I have succeed in my local Ubuntu 14.06, but failed in remote 16.

Comment: Yet, I insist, the uname you show in your original post doesn't look like the one from a Xenial (starting with a 3.13 kernel: that's obviously a Trusty). Are you *certain* your EC2 instance was indeed started from a Xenial AMI?

Comment: Not quite sure. The AMI information shown in EC2 is `Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-7b74c91f
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM),EBS General Purpose (SSD) Volume Type. Support available from Canonical (http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/services).`  I closed this instance and launched another Ubuntu 14 instance, and corresponding deb package, then everything works now.